# Font in FIFA official app

Tags: font-identification

Can someone help identify what font is used for the content in the FIFA app?
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fifa-official-app/id756904853?mt=8

Thank you so much in advance!!

**Edit**
Thank you JohnB and Vicent for all your comments.

By "content", I mean *the content*, eg., the team name, time, scores, etc (sorry, I don't have a better word for it than "content"), not the app title (ie, "FIFA World Cup"), and it seems to me there's only one font.
[image]

I should've also mentioned that before posting the question, I spent a great deal of effort: I searched Google and Quora for the answer with no luck,; I also tried WhatFontIs and Identifont, both yield inaccurate results. Any other tool to recommend?

Answer (score 1):

The font is called miso. It is a free font.
http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/martennettelbladt/miso/buy.html